# How to automatically adjust the column width of datatables

Tags: css, datatables

I am already searched this issue over internet, I have also used their examples too but It did not work on mine. I have datatables with zero configuration setting, what I want to achieve is that I want the column to be auto adjusted based in the contents on the column.

here's my code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable(
            "bAutoWidth":false
            );
        } );

    </script>
```

I have also tried to adjust using the tables but it did not work.

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this in table cell  `width:auto;` ?

Comment: its css style to be added to the element and not class attribute. Hope this helps

Comment: @JaysonLacson style="width:auto;"